# run javascript inside php?

Tags: php, javascript, curl

I need to call arbitrary javascript functions from a page I download with a cURL session inside a php script. For example, on the site x4x4x.tk, I need to call updateLocation() (search for "updateLocation(this)" in the source). I can't have the script pop open a browser window and do it there, it needs to be done entirely from the command line.

I found an extension called v8js that looks like it would do what I need, but it requires php 5.3.3. The server the script will run on uses php 5.2.6-1 and I'm not in a position where I can update the server.

I found the extensions php-js and j4p5 and they look like they'll do what I want, but I wanted to check on here and see if anyone's tried to do anything like this before.

Comment: there are easier ways to interact with a proxy than this.

Comment: try out those libs you mention. if they work for you, add that as an answer and accept it. you might want to link to those for future visitors.

Comment: php-js is quite the opposite of what you're asking

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript - Client Side
PHP - Server Side.

Best guess? Either translate the code, or open a browser window for the client to execute it. otherwise, you're not going to have a fun time getting a javascript file to execute via php/cURL.

Comment: The purpose of the script is to request some random website and run random functions off of it. I'm not going to have any idea of what the functions are. If they were always the same I could just translate it, but it looks like I'm going to have have... "fun"

Comment: [Server Side Javascript](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Server-side_JavaScript) is growing each day, so please dont slapdown the OP with the old JS is client side.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a php extensions that embed javascript engines

- [Spidermonkey JavaScript engine for PHP, embeds Mozilla's Javascript engine Spidermonkey in PHP.](http://pecl.php.net/package/spidermonkey) by Christophe Robin
- [V8 Javascript Engine for PHP, embeds the Google's V8 Javascript Engine into PHP](http://pecl.php.net/package/v8js) by Jani Taskinen

Answer (score 0):

php/curl cant execute/run javascript. You could go with a macro chained to php. Check imacros for that or selenium. Both run a browser able to execute and parse javascript. Maybe hack the output and make it run whatever javascript function you want but it's a long shot. Anyways,  hope it gets you to the right direction, you could go there (selenium, imacros website) and ask further.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those out.